# Creating or Using a VENV File/ Portability

Tags: python, python-venv, pyvenv

[Venv File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWKcM.png) I have a project that utilizes YoloV5, OpenCV, as well as many other python libraries. After finally finishing work on the project, I wanted to share it with my teammates. However, I was unable to get my code to run anywhere other than my machine. There was a Venv file that was generated automatically somewhere along the way, either by my IDE or a jupyter notebook. I tried giving out this file to others, but it is not only massive (~1GB), but it also didn't work. I will consistently get syntax errors that do not exist in my environment. For example, I will get:

"SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xf0' in file detect.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
"

If I remove that line, I get:

"  File "detect.py", line 120
model.warmup(imgsz=(1 if pt else bs, 3, *imgsz))  # warmup
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
"

Mind you, none of these errors exist in my environment.

I have tried looking up various commands to somehow link the venv file to the environment or to the python file. I thought that, perhaps, python wasn't looking for the file, so it wasn't using it. I also tried installing other packages and installing all the dependencies manually. However, none of these things worked. I am a little lost on where to go from here, I have heard of tools like Conda, which apparently might help manage things like this, but I am wondering if anyone could give advice on how to proceed, or maybe if anyone else has personally used YoloV5 and encountered this problem themselves

Comment: It's unclear and unspecific. Anyway, define your python environments - python distribution with its version information and all the required packages with their version information, etc. Are you using ```requirements.txt```?

Comment: Also solve the problem step by step. Specify the encoding of your source code at first. And are you sure you are running the same version of python interpreter on the PC of your mate?

Comment: Virtual environments are not relocatable or portable. Meaning they can not be moved to another location on the same machine (or renamed), and they can work with a different Python interpreter (from Python 3.10 to Python 3.11 for example, or from a Windows machine to a Linux machine, and so on). -- A solution is to export the list of required libraries with `path/to/venv/python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`, transfer this `requirements.txt` file to the new target machine if necessary, and then in a new virtual environment: `path/to/new_venv/bin/python -m pip install -r requierements.txt`.

Comment: I just tried again. Deleted the venv and used the requirements.txt that already exists. For whatever reason, it will only work when I run the install on each requirement individually. The requirements.txt seems to be in the correct format, but it will not work on its own, even after upgrading pip3 and python3. That being said, it does work now. Thanks for your help guys, sorry for the poor question.